# site-packages directory not being added to sys.path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

My question is why `/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/` is not being added to `sys.path`; I expect it to have been added by the site module.

Some details: from within a Docker container, I am using `pip install -e` to install some Python packages in editable mode. The packages get installed to `/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages`; however this directory is not in `sys.path` so I cannot import them.

The [site module docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/site.html) say:

`lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages`... if it refers to an existing directory, and if so, adds it to sys.path. I've confirmed that this directory exists so I expect it to be added.

`python3 -m site` prints:

```
sys.path = [
    '/',
    '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.8',
    '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/root/.local' (doesn't exist)
USER_SITE: '/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer *why*, but adding this line to the Dockerfile seems to work around the issue:

```
RUN echo "/usr/lib/python3.x/site-packages" >> /usr/local/lib/python3.x/dist-packages/site-packages.pth
```

where `x` is your Python minor version.

This workaround is based on the [Modifying Python’s Search Path](https://docs.python.org/3/install/index.html#modifying-python-s-search-path) section of the docs which says:

> The most convenient way [to add a directory] is to add a path configuration file to a directory that’s already on Python’s path ... Path configuration files have an extension of `.pth`, and each line must contain a single path that will be appended to `sys.path`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for a python-3.8 installation (3.9 was fine), I added:

```
COPY usercustomize.py /root/
```

to the `Dockerfile`, with the contents of `usercustomize.py`:

```py
import sys
if sys.version_info[:2] == (3, 8):
    sys.path.append("/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages")
```

Comment: Also seeing this behavior with Python 3.7